# FireDate for UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa

I know how to use `UILocalNotification`.

> My Question is **NOT** related to custom repeatInterval, i know unfortunately it is not possible to set **custom repeatInterval in apple's iOS**.

I have just issue of fire notification on proper date that set by user.

I have use  *(two)* `UISegmentedControl` *(subView of `UIScrollView` )* added on `UIToolBar`.
 such like,

[image]

After show my image, i hope that may be you understand my question very well.

Button **"All"** *(segment button)* want repeat notification daily, and 
I done work with  set
**Repeat  Interval =>** `NSDayCalendarUnit`

But in others buttons ***(sun-to-mon)***?

I must need to set fireDate base on selected day.
SO, how can i get proper date base on selected day??

**For Example:**

If i select **friday** then how can i set my fireDate on date of FriDay ? How can i got it and i also need to repeat notification at specific day whenever its come (i know i need to use `NSWeekCalendarUnit`)?

Comment: have a look at the link http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/09/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html

Comment: @Leena- thanks for replay, i check out few hour ago, but this Anser is not related to my question:(

Comment: @Leena- my datePicker has only time mode so how can i got which day i select from above (image) segment ?? how can i fire on this day ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one local notification for each selected day and set it to repeat weekly. For the all button the repeat interval should be set to daily.

For the weekly repeating button you need to calculate the appropriate start date. To do that you want to use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` Specifically, the `weekday` property of the components. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242791/create-next-nsdate-that-matches-day-nsstring).

Comment: sorry it is not button its a segmentController so don't worry user able to select any one button from **sun-to-mon**, so i doesn't need to create multiple notification, and also it is bad for us. because we can **schedule only - 64** local notification :( and thanks for your golden replay :)

Comment: Should all repeat every day and every week and the day specific buttons should repeat on that day every week?

Comment: **YES**, my 'All'(button) has a repeatInterval = `NSDayCalendarUnit` (it done by me) and issue is... i want to do ,when user select any one button from **sun-to-mon** then notification will repeat on that day .. how can i do ??

Comment: Did you look at the link in my answer and try implementing it?

Comment: but how can i got that how many days are add to current date ??

Comment: `differenceDays` tell you that, but why is it important (other than for debug)? The calculated date is what you need?

Comment: is your answer is help me for me ??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310935/modeling-a-repeating-event-in-a-database-and-using-uilocalnotification-to-fire ..i dont know but may be ??

Comment: @wain- how can apply it in my question ?

Comment: That is a different problem. Your problem is like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242791/create-next-nsdate-that-matches-day-nsstring where you want to add days to the current date.

Comment: thanks for give me your golden time but if i select today's day then how can i get that i does not need to add any days to my current date ??

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve your goal by using `NSWeekCalendarUnit` . But please take care of that **Maximum number of scheduled notification is 64**. If you are reached the maximum you can't add more local notifications without removing the old ones or after firing the scheduled notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSDayCalenderUnit,i hope it will be working for you

Comment: @mani.. please first read my whole question :) and thanks for replay :)